# Redreaw borders of shapes/Split shape into selected grid/Halftoning with triangles

Tags: adobe-illustrator, inkscape, halftone

It's been months I have been trying to find an answer to this, maybe it has been asked before but I was not able to find the answer. I would like to redraw given shapes' borders based onto a triangular grid. The new shape's border points would be on the closest intersection of points of the grid itself, and its lines would always follow the grid's lines. There would be of course loss of definition, but that is the actual purpose of the task.  It would be close to break the shape(s) into its constituting triangles, but they would be merged into a another shape. It would be good if I could actually keep both versions (with merged triangles and not) I found an online program (https://halftonepro.com/app) that does a similar thing to what I am trying to achieve.
I have looked at pages about halftoning, Voronoi, FEM and BEM mesh refinement, but I could not find it.
Any help is really appreciated.
 [image: Sketched sample]

Comment: Not graphic design. But please note you can transform this problem to a oval and square problem which is easy to solve. And mostly how to solve this particular problem is discussed here: https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/ see your triangles are just skewed squares. Anyway youbcould also sove this with a O(n) algorithm easy enough just irerate all vertices and select the ones inside a circle. This is an easy distance test. Then iterate selected points and deselect points that dont have connections to nonselected points.

Comment: Hi joojaa, thanks a lot for the answer. It seems I have to study a bit (a lot!) to be able to put in practice yours and the linked advice...